# Trying to implement level order traversal on a binary search tree in Java

Tags: java

Okay, so I'm trying to make a method that will return the level order of a basic binary search tree that carries int values in its nodes. I've figured out most of the other methods, such as insertion, post order and pre order, but I keep running into the same problem with the level order method

Here's the code:

```
private DoubleStackQueue<Node> queue = new DoubleStackQueue<Node>();
//this is a queue that uses two stacks, one for the front and one for the back.
//it works just like a queue.
public String levelOrder(){  
    s = "";  //The s is a private String that is implemented earlier
    queue.add(this);  
    while (!queue.isEmpty())  
    {  
        Node node = (Node)queue.remove();  
        if (!(node.equals(null))) {s += ""+node.getVal();}  
        if (!(left.equals(null))) {queue.add(node.left);}  
        if (!(right.equals(null))) {queue.add(node.right);}  
    }  
    return s;  
}
```

The main problem that I am having is that, when the program gets to a leaf node, it still adds its children to the queue, even though there are no children, just null, so I'll get a queue that has two nulls in front of the actual item in it. I originally had the if statements as (left != null) and such, but that didn't work either. I'm just trying to figure out how to make the program recognize when there aren't any children. What do I need to do?

Comment: `node.equals(null)` will ALWAYS be false no matter what if it actually completes without exception. that's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several comments:

1. The primary issue is that you're using `left` and `right` instead of `node.left` and `node.right` in your comparisons.
2. To compare against null use `if (var != null)`. Do not use `equals()`. If a variable is null you cannot call methods on it as that will trigger `NullPointerException`s.
3. Once you have fixed your code you will never have `null` inserted into the queue. The first object you add is `this` which is guaranteed to be non-null, and subsequently you always check for null before inserting items onto the queue. That means your first `if (node != null)` check is unnecessary.
4. The cast in `(Node) queue.remove()` should be unnecessary. Your compiler ought to warn you about this.

Result:

```
queue.add(this);

while (!queue.isEmpty())  
{  
    Node node = queue.remove();

    s += "" + node.getVal();

    if (node.left  != null) { queue.add(node.left);  }
    if (node.right != null) { queue.add(node.right); }
}
```

Comment: Okay, it looks like that was exactly the problem. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Within your code I can find the lines

```
if (!(left.equals(null))) {queue.add(node.left);}  
if (!(right.equals(null))) {queue.add(node.right);}
```

where in the condition it states `left` and `right` which are nowhere defined in the parts you show but on the right it reads `node.left` and `node.right`. Is this intentionally? I'd expect also `node.left` and `node.right` in the if conditions.

Comment: I overlooked that. I now have them both as node.left and node.right. when I put those, I intended that they were the children of the node in question. The queue no longer has nulls being added to it, but unfortunately it is still passing through lefts and rights that are null. I just don't understand why it's doing that.

Comment: @Kameron S. If left or right are null your code will not work at all (`node.left.equals` will throw a NullPointerException if this would be the case). Also if no nulls are in the queue how can it still process them? Can you please update your code with the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [Level-order tree traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044336/level-order-tree-traversal)
I believe this is the same thing you're trying to achieve, is it not?  This is a pretty classic problem, so in my experience it's been discussed over-and-over before.

Comment: It is, but I'm afraid it does not answer my question. I'm wondering how, when I know that both the left and right nodes are null, they still get added to the queue. I know that's not supposed to happen.